# How to proxy traffic with failover based on http error codes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, http

There are two endpoints. I want:

- proxy / service in front of two endpoints
- send all requests to a chosen primary endpoint
- if the primary responds with e.g. 404, a failover happens sending the request to the chosen secondary endpoint
- cache failed primary endpoint requests to avoid having to check every time

Is there a proxy / service that can achieve this with no effort from my side other than configuration?

Comment: Load balancer handles traffic depending on the load balancing algorithm we configured at backend and by default it uses Round Robin Algorithm.

Please find this docs which might help you in understanding the Configuration of LB failover :


https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/failover-overview
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/failover-overview#connection_draining
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12530_01/oam.1014/e10353/failover.htm

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Gabriel Stein : Have you seen the above comment? Is this usefull?

Comment: @HemanthKumar yes, I saw it. no, it is not useful. but thanks.